# replacing an element value in a vector

Tags: c++

so i am doing a inventory program. I have a vector of class items in it and I want to user enter Id and then run an iterator to match with the Id that is in the vector and change the value of the quantity sold:

here is part of my code:

```
 vector<Item>::const_iterator it;
  for(it=items.begin(); it !=items.end(); it++){
    if (it->getID() == id){
      amount=it->getactual()-sold;
      it->setactual(amount);
```

that is in my class

```
int getactual()const{return actual_quantity;}
void setactual(int quantity){actual_quantity=quantity;}
```

but i get an error: passing ‘const Item’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void Item::setactual(int)’ discards qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
vector<Item>::iterator
```

instead of

```
vector<Item>::const_iterator
```

`const_iterator` means read-only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a const iterator but you are modifying what it points to (calling non-const members), try using a regular iterator:

```
vector<Item>::iterator it;
```

Answer (score 1):

`setactual` obviously cannot operate on a `const` object (as the one that you obtain via a `const_iterator`; change `const_iterator` to plain `iterator`.